# Do we really need to host assetlinks.json file for an Android App?

Tags: android, google-identity-toolkit, google-identity, fido

According to Google FIDO Documentation, Only websites require digital asset link file for interoperability.

> https://developers.google.com/identity/fido/android/native-apps#interoperability_with_your_website

Do we really need to host **assetlinks.json** file for an android app which uses custom fido server?

Comment: It depends on you whether you want to make your app versatile/self-updating or static.

Comment: Actually I tried without hosting a assetlinks.json file on domain. 
Android FIDO Platform Authenticator always returns SECURITY_ERR (The incoming request cannot be validated.) 
Any idea?

Comment: What kind of security error? CORS?

Comment: Ref: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fido/fido2/api/common/ErrorCode#public-static-final-errorcode-security_err

Answer (score 0):

Having just implemented a fido server, you most definitely need to have the assetslinks.json file hosted on a publicly accessible site.

Your phone sends a request to a public Google server which then loads and validates the assetslinks.json file before returning an ok/bad response back to the phone.

I've not had a chance to confirm if it needs to be https (but from recollection) the doco suggests that it can be either HTTPS or HTTP.